# Specific post user permissions

Tags: plugins, user-roles

in that gives a specific user the option 
Edit a specific post 
I searched and found only plug-in that give the user the option to edit all posts 
But I did not see anything reference to a specific post 
I tried to use as a plug-in "user permissions" but unfortunately it does not save my settings 
Thank you

Comment: Questions are meant to be references for later visitors as well. Please rework your questions spelling/punctuation/grammar/capitalization so it as as easy to read as possible. In its current state, it's impossible to understand what your question is. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can conditionally control which [user role has the capability](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Contributor) to  edit posts

```
edit_posts
```

By default, contributors can edit their posts however you can add or remove capabilities for different roles and user i.d's.

```
add_action( 'init', 'new_role_edit_posts' ); 

function new_role_edit_posts() {

if ( is_single('007') {

$role = get_role( 'new-role' );
$role->add_cap( 'edit_posts' );
    }
}
```

This enables the new user role named new-role to edit the single post with the post i.d of 007

You will need to [create a new role](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_role) named new-role

Comment: But every time I want to add a user to post I will have to create a new role?

There is no plug-in that makes it easier?

Comment: Plugin recommendations are off topic here. I suggest you use one role which only allows edits_posts for users posts i.e contributor or create a new custom role.