# Allow contributors to create page (but not publish)

Tags: pages, permissions

Contributors [can create post drafts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Contributor) but not publish. I'd like to add the same permission concept but to Pages. That is, can I allow a Contributor to create a page draft only to have an Editor/Admin to later approve or reject?

From this [question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/133902/), I see that I can hook into the action `new_role_edit_posts`. Is there an equivalent `new_role_edit_pages`?

How would you go about this?

Answer (score 3):

> How would you go about this?

I see this is an old question and that you found a solution with an existing plugin. However, since this is a development StackExchange, it's probably better if there's an answer that explains how to accomplish the stated goals without the need for a third-party plugin.

#### Written Answer

WordPress stores capabilities in the database. Therefore, what we want is a plugin that will add the `edit_pages` capability to the contributor role upon plugin activation. For completeness, the plugin should remove the capability upon deactivation.

#### Coded Answer

```
/**
 * Plugin Name: WPSE 230940
 */

//* Add activation hook
register_activation_hook( __FILE__ ,  'wpse_230940_activation' );    
function wpse_230940_activation() {
  //* Add edit_pages capability to contributors
  $contributor = get_role( 'contributor' );
  $contributor->add_cap( 'edit_pages' );
}

//* Add deactivation hook
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__ , 'wpse_230940_deactivation' );
function wpse_230940_deactivation() {
  //* Remove edit_pages capability from contributors
  $contributor = get_role( 'contributor' );
  $contributor->remove_cap( 'edit_pages' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same thing using wp-cli.

```
wp cap add 'contributor' 'edit_pages'
```

Answer (score -1):

A plugin to the rescue. It looks like [WPFront User Role Editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpfront-user-role-editor/) is what I was looking for. It produces a very granulated menu of what each role can do. This looks promising.

[image]

Comment: Nice, next time you do a search before asking here I hope?! Coming up with a plugin as answer seems pretty fishy to me.

Comment: Yes, I did find this almost after I posted. There is no ill intent. It's a maintained plugin. I feel it's best for the community for two reasons. One, someone smarter may come along and provide a *better* answer. This is my primary hope. Two, someone else may have a similar question. I'd be delighted that I helped the community.

Comment: Wrong, for plugins ppl can look themselves in the plugin repositories. To find help for *(own)* code/development issues this forum exist. [Read](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), WordPress Stack Exchange is for theme and plugin **development**. Just a hint Richard, take a visit next time on [IRC](http://webchat.freenode.net/) at #wordpress channel, lots of devs which will help(Live help) you out.(*if possible ofcourse*)